# openwrt using iptables with tee seems broken

Tags: iptables, openwrt, snort

I've been trying to set up port mirroring on openwrt version 14.07 following [this guide](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/netfilter):

however the command:

```
$iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING  -o br-lan ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.254
```

produces the following error:

> $iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Doe's anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To me the above command seems perfectly fine, except for the position of the NOT (=`!`) operator:

```
 $iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING  -o br-lan -s ! 192.168.0.0/16 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.254
```

EDIT:

If it still does not work, that's because you are missing some of the iptables modules. You can find them [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/netfilter#opkg_netfilter_packages), it is imposisble for me to know which one you are missing, you may wish to try them out. You will surely need

```
    insmod ipt_route
```

for the above iptables command to work, plus, like I said, perhaps more.

Should this all fail, [this Googl Code page](https://code.google.com/p/port-mirroring/) presents an easy alternative to doing it with iptables.

Comment: typing the like yours i get:
'$ Bad argument `192.168.0.0/16''

Comment: @SnakeByte Please see my edit.

Comment: sadly even went so far as install of iptables packages. still can't run 
'code' insmod ipt_route : $Failed to find ipt_route. Maybe it is a built in module ?

Comment: I did try running port-mirroring before coming here, it was not very successful:
$port-mirroring: can't load library 'libpcap.so.1.1'
libpcap is installed properly though